# Check if a string starts with a decimal digit?

Tags: string, parsing, go

It looks the following works, is it a good approach?

```
var thestr = "192.168.0.1"
if (thestr[0]>= '0' && thestr[0] <= '9'){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you parse it to a number and check or use a regular expression?

Comment: @epascarello because that would be massive overkill if the OP really only needs to know about the first character. If they instead want to parse/check for an IP address then they should be using something from the `net` package.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is completely fine.

But note that strings in Go are stored as a read-only byte slice where the bytes are the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence, and indexing a string indexes its *bytes*, not its runes (characters). But since a decimal digit (`'0'..'9'`) has exactly one byte, it is ok in this case to test the first `byte`, but first you should test if `len(s) > 0` or `s != ""`.

Here are some other alternatives, try all on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/TPnh9FmUsj):

#### 1) Testing the byte range:

This is your solution, probably the fastest one:

```
s := "12asdf"
fmt.Println(s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9')
```

#### 2) Using [`fmt.Sscanf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscanf):

Note: this also accepts if the `string` starts with a negative number, decide if it is a problem for you or not (e.g. accepts `"-12asf"`).

```
i := 0
n, err := fmt.Sscanf(s, "%d", &i)
fmt.Println(n > 0, err == nil) // Both n and err can be used to test
```

#### 3) Using [`unicode.IsDigit()`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsDigit):

```
fmt.Println(unicode.IsDigit(rune(s[0])))
```

#### 4) Using [`regexp`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/):

I would probably never use this as this is by far the slowest, but here it is:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`^\d`)
fmt.Println(r.FindString(s) != "")
```

Or:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`^\d.*`)
fmt.Println(r.MatchString(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use regexps for that simple task :)

What I would change in this case:

- add check for empty string before checking for the first rune
- I would rephrase it as "starts with a digit" as the number semantic is too broad. `.5e-45` is a number, but probably it is not what you want. 0's semantic is also not simple: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238737/why-do-some-people-state-that-zero-is-not-a-number

Answer (score -1):

Since you are comparing by character and no characters are between 1 and 9, I think your solution is ok, but it does not account for the other numbers following.

For example, if `thestr` was `"192.something.invalid"` it's no longer an IP.

I'd recommend using a regular expression to check the IP.

something like

```
\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b
```